# How to trigger infrequent interaction events without manually checking for input every frame?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback

I am brand new to Unity, and have quite a basic question.

So far, I have been checking if a key is pressed every single frame (just in a main "Update()" method), in order to handle player movement. This is fine, because I expect movement will be happening pretty much every single frame anyway.

My question is about how to handle events that don't happen often - say once every 10 min. For example, pausing the game. I don't want to check every single frame if the pause key was pressed, like this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) ) {
            // Move (this happens pretty much every frame)
        }
        
        if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) ) {
            // Pause game (this hardly ever happens)
        }
        
        // Check for many more possible interactions ...
    }
}
```

There could be many such infrequent events (fire, jump, etc). I know that it shouldn't really slow the game down having lots of "if" statements, but it would be much nicer if this could be done with a callback style action.

I am aware of delegates and listeners in c#/Unity, but these are really a way to handle what happens after an event has been fired/published, so it's not really what my question is about. Furthermore, I am more asking about how to *trigger* such an event without some kind of checking every single frame going on. Is it even possible in Unity?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to check every frame?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for unity's new input system.

Comment: @PhillipZoghbi as I said, it's not very elegant, and they will be almost all redundant checks. Would be much nicer if Unity could fire off a notification.

Comment: @shingo Yes I have seen that the new input system allows to define an "action" and bind it to a key press. This raises two questions: 1) was this not possible to do before the new input manager came along? 2) what is the new input manager doing behind the scenes (is it simply checking every frame)?

Comment: I claim 1) No, at least not out of the box ... 2) no clue but tbh I doubt that you should be concerned about efficiency for either options ... InputActions gives you the callback style you're looking for + additional other flexibilities and features you don't have with the `Input` class .... how this one internally works exactly shouldn't be too much of a concern for you .. there are most probably other places where you can optimize first ;) Probably even using some native parts that usually are already quite efficient

Comment: @derHugo good advice :) I will spend some time finally learning how to use the new input actions system properly now.

Comment: `Event` + `OnGUI` could be the closest though I have tested. I only know that the new input system uses [an internal interface](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Modules/Input/Private/InputModule.bindings.cs), which is an OS based implementation.

Comment: @teeeeee it looks by far more complicated than it is actually .. I was hesitating a lot but once you get into it it is actually pretty cool ;)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no, you can't

Checking the inputs at everys frame is a necessity and still will be done under the hood with an event based input system, there is nothing "more optimized".

With the "New Input System", you already have access to these events, with the "Old Input Manager", you have to create your own events

If you want, you can create an event yourself easily.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class InputEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action OnPausePressed;

    [SerializedField] private KeyCode _pauseKey;
    [SerializedField] private string _pauseButton;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(_pauseKey) || Input.GetButtonDown(_pauseButton)) {
            OnPausePressed?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass {
    public void MyMethodToRegister() {
        InputEvents.OnPausePressed -= PausePressed;
        InputEvents.OnPausePressed += PausePressed;
    }

    public void MyMethodToUnregister() {
        InputEvents.OnPausePressed -= PausePressed;
    }

    private void PausePressed() {
        Debug.Log("Pause the game here");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What makes you think that using the callback approach (as in the example in the answer below) is still checking every frame? Do you have a link or reference for that? It may be true, but I was always under the impression that callbacks worked fundamentally differently to polling (in every programming language, not just c# / Unity). If not, I am really misunderstanding the idea behind them... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After doing some extensive research, I've come to the conclusion that [`InputSystem` package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.6/manual/Installation.html) is your best bet.

How it's handled in the back end is very platform-specific, which is why Unity wrote the package itself.

To achieve a similar thing to your inquiry in C#, you'd have to use `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, and a `Control.KeyPress Event` class, which is, once again, platform-specific, and that assembly won't work with Unity due the incompatibility issues. You can do it in C# though, outside the engine. If you're extremely curious, check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

In every other case, feel confident to rely on the `InputSystem` because it's exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments and answer from Phillip Zoghbi, the Input System package does indeed provide the behaviour I looking for. In case it helps anyone, a minimum working example of this approach is given below.

First make sure the "*Input System*" is installed from the *Package Manager* menu.

Then, right click in the project Assets folder --> "*Create*" --> "*Input Action*". Open it and create an action map, along with actions and bindings for the move keys and the pause button:

[image]

Next, use "*Generate C# Class*" file for this Input Action Asset, which automatically creates a C# file (for me called `MyInputActions.cs`).

Now I have two more scripts. The first is `MyGameInputs.cs` which handles all game inputs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyGameInputs : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event EventHandler OnPauseGameAction;
    private MyInputActions myInputActions;

    private void Awake(){
        myInputActions = new MyInputActions();
        myInputActions.MyActionMap.Enable(); 
        myInputActions.MyActionMap.PauseGame.performed += PauseGame_performed;
    }

    private void PauseGame_performed( UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext obj){
        OnPauseGameAction?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public Vector3 getMoveDir(){
        Vector3 moveDirection = myInputActions.MyActionMap.Move.ReadValue<Vector3>();
        return moveDirection;
    }
}
```

The second is a controller script for the player `MyPlayerController.cs` which reacts to the inputs:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyPlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MyGameInputs myGameInputs;
    private Vector3 moveDirection;

    private void Start(){
        myGameInputs.OnPauseGameAction += myGameInputs_OnPauseGameAction;
    }

    private void myGameInputs_OnPauseGameAction(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
        Debug.Log("Pause Key Pressed");
        // Perform actions when pause key pressed
    }

    private void Update(){
        moveDirection = myGameInputs.getMoveDir();
        Debug.Log(moveDirection);
        // Act according to move input keys
    }
}
```

The move function behaves in much the same way as in the original post (in the sense that it is still checking for move input every single frameu), but is now using the `ReadValue()` method from the new input system.

However, now the "Pause Game" function is done using a callback instead of polling. This is done by using the ["performed"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Actions.html#responding-to-actions) phase of the action in the `MyGameInputs.cs` script, where the function `PauseGame_performed()` fires an event called `OnPauseGameAction`.

Then finally the `MyPlayerController.cs` script is listening for the `OnPauseGameAction` event, and will run the function  `myGameInputs_OnPauseGameAction` when it fires.

In this way, a callback is used to do the triggering (instead of polling), and both the input script and the player script are completely decoupled (with the communication done by notification of an event).